# Viewing domain from within network

Tags: linux

We have an internal web server running Debian 6 squeeze. Our Netgear UTM25 port forwards port 80 to the server and everything works well from the outside world. However, we are unable to access our domain from within the same LAN - I can access the web server by IP, but not by domain.

How can I set it up so that it translates our domain to the web server's IP?

The domain is employees.DOMAIN.com which points to our public IP on Network Solutions whois.

Comment: Have you done a traceroute from inside the LAN?

Comment: I haven't tried it on a windows machine as there's no traceroute installed. on another linux server it says 30 hops max, 60 byte packets, send: operation not permitted

Comment: You should have the command `tracert` on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Your NetGear router most probably only forwards connections from the outside to the internal webserver, but leaves connections from the inside untouched. If you want to solve this, you have two options:

1. Configure your internal DNS resolver (most likely your NetGear) to respond with the webserver's internal address.
2. Add the host name to every computer's hosts file on the local network.